# How to control your FTP server thru batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

Im making an app, which has a login system, and that login system is linked to a FTP server, the problem is, i dont know how to connect, upload, download files from FTP thru batch, here is some codes that i tried:

```
@echo off
echo user (user)> ftpcmd.dat
echo (pass)>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat (serv name)
del ftpcmd.dat
```

This one works, it does connect to the server, but after connecting, it doesnt execute the command that is coming up (after it connects, it stays on the connected page, it doesnt do anything)

Please, dont hold this, tell me if you didnt understand anything, as i already have 2 holds right now, im trying to stay put as possible, im trying to make my app nicely, please, just tell me if you dont understand.

```
C:\Users\(CENSORED)>ftp server36.000webhost.com
Connected to server36.000webhost.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 13 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:21. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
```

Some time later...

```
C:\Users\(CENSORED)>ftp server36.000webhost.com
Connected to server36.000webhost.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 13 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:21. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Connection closed by remote host.
```

(Its stuck here, doesnt even give a thing)

Comment: Check the contents of ftpcmd.dat, see if the command you were expecting has been written properly?

Comment: Yes it is writed completely :)

Comment: Cool, does it work if you do them one by one at a cmd prompt yourself, not from the file?

Comment: yep, and its stuck on the welcome thingy (I cant put any codes)

Comment: Lose the `-n` flag

Comment: @SomethingDark nah, even i "ftp (server name)" it is still stuck

Comment: Change `quit` to `bye`

Comment: What does it mean *"it stays on the connected page"*? Show us the output dump or screenshot.

Comment: I have no idea on how to paste it here, when i paste it it scrambled up, but heres a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/uMaWaq7r

Comment: What is the output that you have posted? It shows how you execute `ftp server36.000webhost.com`. Where do you execute the batch file?

Comment: in command prompt

Comment: take a look at [Send commands to a cmd window through a .bat file - Rejected StackOverflow question](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesnt work :(